# Expand Paypal Express Checkout, if a downloadable product

Tags: magento, express-checkout, paypal

It really frustrates me, because I'm a while with such a simple change requirement.

I would like to display a simple checkbox in the checkout-review layout, when a downbloadable product in the cart.

I tried with the following code, but it shows no effect

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_downloadable>
    <reference name="paypal.express.review">
        <block type="checkout/specialdownloadagreements" name="specialdownloadagreements"  template="page/html/specialdownloadagreements.phtml" />
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_downloadable>
```

This following code works, but is shows, if it is a simple product only

```
<paypal_express_review translate="label">
    <reference name="paypal.express.review">
        <block type="checkout/special_agreements" name="special.agreements"  template="page/html/special_agreements.phtml" />
    </reference>
</paypal_express_review>
```